# gphoto2 movie capture error: no Viewfinder mode for Canon EOS 400D Rebel XTi

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg, canon, v4l, gphoto2

I recently got an Canon EOS 400D to use as a webcam for recording videos. I checked `gphoto2` documentation to make sure that it can work as a webcam. The [documentation](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/) says "Yes" for the Liveview/webcam column for 400D:

[image]

I used [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqrZrKC1WA0) YouTube tutorial to set it up and run it as a webcam. Things I did:

1. Install `gphoto2`, `v4l2loopback-utils`, and `ffmpeg`
2. Unload `v4l2loopback` using: `sudo rmmod v4l2loopback`
3. Activate v4l2loopback using: s`udo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 max_buffers=2`
4. Stream camera: `gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2`

However, I keep running into an error with `gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie`

> Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
>
> *** Error ***
>
> An error occurred in the io-library ('Could not claim the USB device'): Could not claim interface 0
> (Device or resource busy). Make sure no other program
> (gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor) or kernel module (such as sdc2xx,
> stv680, spca50x) is using the device and you have read/write access to
> the device.
>
> ERROR: Movie capture error... Exiting. Movie capture
> finished (0 frames)

I don't understand. Have I read the documentation wrong and there's no way 400D can work as a webcam? or am I missing something?

I'm using:

> gphoto2         2.5.27
> libgphoto2      2.5.27
> libgphoto2_port 0.12.0
> Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 on wayland
> Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic
> CPU: Intel i7-8565U (8) @ 4.600GHz
> GPU: Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Gr
> GPU: AMD ATI Radeon 540/540X/550/550